# Need help on conversion statement

Tags: php, python

I'm new to python, I should convert the following operation in php:

```
if len (s) == 88:
    return s[48] + s[81:67: -1] + s[82] + s[66:62: -1] + s[85] + s[61:48 : -1] + s[67] + s[47:12: -1] + s[3] + s[11:3: -1] + s[2] + s[12]
```

I do not understand exactly what you mean this formatting `s[a:b: -c]`.

Comment: It is called as slicing. more [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s = "012345678910"
a = 7
b = 4
c = 1
print s[a:b: -c]
```

returns:

```
765
```

So to explain, its a [slice](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) between position 7 in the string and position 4, first element is element 0, in steps of minus one. That is to say, you get every element between 7 and 4 not including 4.

The general form of a slice as detailed in the docs is **slice(start, stop[, step])**.